# Lindenbaum-Theorem only concerning sentential logic provable in ZF?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axiom-of-choice

Is the Lindenbaum-Theorem of sentential logic (= propositional logic) provable in ZF (i. e. without the axiom of choice)?

Lindenbaum's theorem of sentential logic states that every set $\Sigma$ of sentences of the propositional calculus can be enlarged to a maximal consistent set $\Gamma$ of sentences of the propositional calculus.

To prove this theorem concerning the whole predicates logic you need the axiom of choice. My question is, whether you need the axiom of choice to prove Lindenbaum's theorem if you only consider sentential logic.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please elaborate a bit on your question, so more people will know what you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks. I added some text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. Because your propositional logic could have a "strange" number of propositional variables.

If you assume, however, that there are only countably many propositional variables, then you can prove without the aid of the axiom of choice that there are only countably many propositions to write. Then you can enumerate them, and start enlarging your theory one step at a time by going through the enumeration; and at the end you get a maximal consistent theory.

Lesser known fact is that this theorem when applied to propositional calculus, and when applied predicate calculus, both have the same "choice strength". Which in the countable case is none, and in the general case is the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a genius!

Comment: I don't know about that. I just meddled with these things a lot.

Comment: I have more questions 1. How do you know that? Is there literature about that topic? 2. Does the following hold: $ZF\vdash LB_{SL}\rightarrow LB_{PL}$ where $LB_{SL}$ is Lindenbaum's theorem of sentential logic and $LB_{PL}$ is Lindenbaum's theorem of predicate logic?

Comment: How do I know what?

Comment: So you say that $ZF\not\vdash LB_{SL}$. Does one need the axiom of choice to prove the fact that $ZF\not\vdash LB_{SL}$?

Comment: All the usual independence results can be formalized and proved in $\sf PA$, and in other weaker fragments of arithmetics. So the axiom of choice is certainly not needed for that proof.

Comment: You know that $ZF\not\vdash LB_{SL}$. I ask how you know that. Where have you read this?

Comment: Jech "The Axiom of Choice", Chapter 2. He formalizes this as "The Consistency Principle" and it's not immediate as to what's the relationship to this theorem, but a little bit of thinking will get you there.

Comment: Thanks. Why don't you publish this result? Is it too easy?^^ Do you think that $ZF\vdash LB_{SL}\rightarrow LB_{PL}$? I don't think so...

Comment: Mostly because it's a well-established result from the 1950-1960's or so.

Comment: Does one know who discovered the theorem $ZF\not\vdash LB_{SL}$?

Comment: If my memory serves me right, this would be Henkin. But this surely appears in the Historical Notes of the Jech book I mentioned. I will have time to check it up later.

Comment: Okay, that would be nice ;-D

Comment: We know that $ZF\vdash LB_{PL}\rightarrow AC$. Is it also true that $ZF\vdash LB_{SL}\rightarrow AC$?

Comment: We know that? I thought that I wrote in my answer that we don't know that, in fact we know the negation of it.

Comment: Lindenbaum's theorem in general (i. e., for predicate logic) is equivalent to the axiom of choice. So it implies the axiom of choice. That's $ZF\vdash LB_{PL}\rightarrow AC$. What's wrong?

Comment: Where did you read that it is equivalent to the axiom of choice? Remember that Lindenbaum has more than one theorem under his belt as a mathematician.

Comment: Here: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Lindenbaum

Comment: I don't know German well enough to say what's what. But if you can read English, you'll see in the English version of that page that this is a special case of the Ultrafilter Lemma; which is provably weaker than the axiom of choice.

Comment: The theorem I am speaking about is: Every set $\Sigma$ of sentences of the predicate calculus can be enlarged to a maximal consistent set $\Gamma$ of sentences of the predicate calculus. I call this theorem $LB_{PL}$ and thought that $ZF\vdash LB_{PL}\rightarrow AC$. You are sure that this insn't the case?

Comment: Yes. Pretty sure. More than a year ago, since a couple of months ago I had to muddle through some of the related proofs, and I can assure you, that if the German version says that it is *equivalent* to the axiom of choice (and not just that you misread the statement saying that you just have to use *some* choice to prove this), then the German version is wrong.

Comment: The german version says "gewisse Generalisierungen des Satzes sind sogar äquivalent zum Auswahlaxiom": "some generalizations of this theorem are even equivalent to the axiom of choice". I remember that somebody said even $LB_{PL}$ is equivalent to the AC.

Comment: Dr. Wolfgang Burmeister (by the way: he won three gold medals at the International Mathematical Olympiad) wrote (http://www.matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?post_id=1502092&topic=205321): "Übrigens ist der Satz von Lindenbaum in seiner allgemeinen Fassung äquivalent zum Auswahlaxiom, das wurde 1981 von Wojciech Dzik bewiesen."

Comment: (1) I don't know who Wolfgang Burmeister is; (2) achieving something in one field of mathematics does not mean that you know much about other fields; (3) people make mistakes all the time, even me; (4) I think it's quite obvious why the compactness/completeness theorem imply $LP_{PL}$ (every consistent theory has a model, the theory of a model is always complete), and I can tell you with as much certainly as mathematically possible, that the compactness theorem does not imply the axiom of choice. Generalizations of it? Depends on the generalization.

Comment: Okay, I believe you. I just wanted to tell you why I was wondering.

Comment: Do you know whether $ZF\vdash LB_{SL} \rightarrow LB_{PL}$? Should I ask this in another thread?

Comment: Yes, this implication is true. Simply because $LB_{SL}$ implies the ultrafilter lemma, which in turn implies $LB_{PL}$. Read the proof in Jech to which I sent you, it's all there, really. If you have additional questions after that, I'll be happy to try and help.

Comment: Thanks. This is counterintuitive. Because $LB_{PL}$ seams to be (and is) a generalization of $LB_{SL}$.

Comment: I looked up the historical remarks in Jech's book "The Axiom of Choice": Henkin has shown the equivalence "Prime Ideal Theorem <-> Compactness theorem". Did you use this equivalence to prove $ZF\not\vdash LB_{SL}$? Or which equivalence did you use in the little bit of thinking?

Comment: As I wrote in the previous comments, you can show that Lindenbaum's theorem for propositional calculus is equivalent to the "consistency principle" as presented in Jech's book. The proof is in fact using the consistency principle in order to prove this equivalence, and I believe that this route of proof was taken by Henkin originally.

Comment: So you use the consistency principle to show the equivalence "lindenbaum's theorem for propositional calculus <-> consistency principle"?

Comment: More or less, yes.

Comment: So you used the consistency principle to show the equivalence "$LB_{SL}$ <-> consistency principle". You used this result to show "$ZF\not\vdash LB_{SL}$". You said that "$ZF\not\vdash LB_{SL}$" can be shown without the axiom of choice. But in your own proof you used it because you used the consistency principle, right?

Comment: I think that you are in a bit over your head here. This site is not meant for lengthy discussions in the comments, and I think that we're way beyond the point where this is no longer a comment thread, but a conversation thread. So it's better to stop. I'll leave you with two points (1) You're mixing two things that I said. ***Proving*** independence can be done in weak arithmetical theories. Where $LB_{SL}$ being equivalent to the consistency principle is just a theorem of $\sf ZF$, so if it cannot prove one, it will not the other. (2) Take a break for a day, then try to make sense into it.

Comment: What do you mean with "if it cannot prove one, it will not the other"? Why can't we have a conversation? Who minds?

Comment: (1) I mind, mainly because I feel that I am going in circles; (2) the moderators are being notified about long conversations thread and usually migrate them to the chat, which I in general avoid using; (3) If $T$ cannot prove $\varphi$ and $T$ can prove $\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$, then $T$ cannot possibly prove $\psi$.

Comment: Where is something written about the proof of the equivalence "$LB_{SL}$ <-> consistency principle" in Jech's book "The Axiom of Choice"? I can't find.